# VFX scene offset in compositor but not anywhere else

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking

I have a scene I'm developing using Blender's VFX tools.  Object was tracked in the video (png sequence), error was under 0.4, and I managed to model my object to fit as perfect as I care to.  Once I go into the compositor and run an update render, the object eventually shifts by noticeable amounts in the compositor and render, but not when I'm in the layout tab.

Layout tab:

[image]

Compositor tab:

[image]

To address a short list of questions that may come to mind:

1. I've applied all transforms on the can object
2. Both screenshots were taken at the same frame in the animation
3. The dimensions of my animation is the same dimensions as the png sequence
4. To be clear, the finger mask is irrelevant to this question, it's a WIP and makes no difference here
5. When I solved the camera motion, I refined the whole list
6. The can object is stationary with no animation

Why is my can object shifting to the left in the compositor and render, but not in other tabs like Layout?

Comment: What is the purpose of the scale node in the compositor? Did you solve the camera or did you solve as object?

Comment: Scale got added by Blender as part of when I setup the tracking scene (I believe).  There was also a distort node that was blurring the edges of my scene that got deleted.  Second question: I'm actually not sure which I did or that I even know that there's a difference.  I just checked tripod, selecting a 15-frame range, selected the whole kit under refine and hit solve camera motion.

Comment: To confirm, removing the Scale node does not appear to have much of an effect.  The can object appears to drift slightly off to the left as the animation progresses.

Comment: One step at the time. To track an object you don't need to solve the camera. In the properties window on the right (press N to make it visible in the clip editor) open the track tab. Then on the Objects section you will see that  the default is to track  camera, but if you press on the + sign you can create an object to track. Track as usual. Then on Solve section you will see Solve Object Motion, which sounds more like what you need. Please report back if that is not the case.

Comment: You might find this video interesting: [Hand matchmoving tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0d1QnS29y0&list=PLW007QhybFgeTIhw4mrnZKRQGqOrREv17)

Comment: what happens if you remove the scale node?